# Print to EPS file in Windows 10

Tags: windows, eps, postscript

In Windows 7 and older versions I did this to generate EPS:

1. I installed a driver for a postcript printer (from HP for example).
2. Set "file" as printer port, so that output was directed to a file instead of to an actual printer.
3. Accessed the driver's postscript properties and set it to produce EPS files.
4. After the file was printed, I needed to "convert to EPS" and set bounding box with the GSView program.

After step 4, the EPS file could be succesfully inserted as a figure in a LaTeX document. I used for example Word to draw the figure, generate the EPS file, and it could be succesfully inserted with `\includegraphics`.

My problem is that in Windows 10 I can't do step 3. I have tried many drivers and none of them seems to offer postscript properties. They do produce files, but when I insert them in a LaTeX document the figure doesn't show correctly, or GSView gives errors when displaying the document. I think the reason is that the file is not a valid EPS file.

So, my questions are:

- Is there a postscript driver that will allow me to access postscript properties in Windows 10?
- Failing that, how can I print to EPS files in Windows 10?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use diagram drawing software that produces eps files directly (e.g. [geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/))?

Comment: @IanThompson Maybe... but I'm used to Word (I only need simple block diagrams etc). And in any case I'd like to have a general solution to produce usable EPS files from any program

Comment: This looks off-topic to me: yes you want to use the output with TeX, but you need Windows knowledge here. (Can't you print to PDF then convert from  PDF to EPS?)

Comment: I think it would be quite easy to draw simple diagrams with geogebra. If you print to eps from arbitrary applications you probably won't get a vector image. Instead you will get a bitmap embedded in an eps, which will distort (especially if it contains text such as labels). You may as well use a png file (in which case you would need to compile with pdflatex).

Comment: @IanThompson Yes, they are probably not vector, so png would do. How to produce a png (with enough resolution) then? Is there something like a driver to "print to png" from an arbitrarry application?

Comment: Why don't you produce `.pdf` graphic files! I suppose most application understand the .pdf format?

Comment: I expect that Word can save diagrams as png files. To get an image from an arbitrary application, you could take a screenshot.

Comment: @Bernard How would I produce pdf files? Printing to pdf directly doesn't generate a figure usable with `\includegraphics`

Comment: @IanThompson Word doesn't save as png. A screenshot will have very low quality, as the number of pixels is limited by the screen

Comment: I don't know Word, but can't it export to.pdf like *Libre Office*?

Comment: @Bernard It can print to/save as pdf, but that pdf cannot be used as a figure file

Comment: Do you mean it is a whole page? There is a excellent tool `epspdf-setup` , available on CTAN, which is able to convert between `eps` and `pdf` formats, cropping to a tight bounding box.

Comment: @Bernard It is a whole page, but I'm not sure that's the only thing that prevents it from being used correctly with `\includegraphics`. I'll try that tool, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome. Please let me know if it works  when you test it.

Comment: @Bernard It doesn't work :-( It says "unreadable or unsopported type" when I try to open the pfd file I printed from Word (it's pdf 1.4 and I can correctly open it with Adobe Reader)

Comment: @Bernard It doesn't open ps files either. Maybe I need to install something else? I only installed [this](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/epspdf-setup) (and I have MikTeX)

Comment: Could you post the .pdf you printed from Word?   Epspdf (not epstopdf) can manage .eps, .ps and .pdf files (it doesn't visualise them, it only converts between them). I have only  `epspdf` and `MiKTeX` too.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for that. I'm using [this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nka1mq0rexo63cj/tmp.pdf?dl=0) as a test

Comment: The solution, as I tested it, is to convert first the .pdf to .eps (with option `tight bounding box`), then back to .pdf (same option).

Comment: @Bernard But it doesn't even allow me to open the pdf file with program `epspdftk` (it's that one, right? Sorry for being dense)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34208/discussion-between-bernard-and-luis-mendo).

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party this side but thought I would add in my solution in case anyone still needs it. Ran into the same problem you did on windows 10 as I couldn't work out how to print EPS files. This is what I did my side and it seems to have worked!

basically, windows 10 stopped supporting PCL5 according to this:
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00751649

but if you install the "HP universal driver for windows" from here:
http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=4157320

you can download drivers for windows 10 specifically, and in the driver listing there is:

> HP Universal Print Driver for Windows PostScript (64-bit)  6.2.1.20636

Install this driver, and when it prompts you select

1. Traditional mode
2. Local printer or network printer with manual settings
3. Print to File
4. Install printer driver "HP Universal Printing PS (v6.2.1)"

This then gives you a printer with all the nifty postscript features, and if you print to Encapsulated mode seems to play nicely with Ghostview.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that (not at the work computer right now)

Comment: I tried this. It almost works for me. It produces correct `.eps` files, which I can compile with `latex` and `dvips` to a `ps` file. However, it fails when I try to produce a `pdf` file. Using `ps2pdf` with the `dEPSCrop` option to convert the figure produces a blank image in the pdf

Answer (score 1):

Update 22Aug22:
It looks like GSView has been discontinued, so the CutePDF printer plus GSView to fix the bounding boxes no longer works.

Instead you can save the picture as svg file type. (If using excel, first copy it to word or powerpoint). Then install Inkscape and open the svg in inkscape. Then save as type eps.

---

Old answer:
You can install the CutePDF printer. That still allows you to set the format to eps in the advanced options.

Take care when installing to decline all the unwanted extras (ask toolbar etc)

This works with excel plots, but unfortunately word documents (required by the poster) always come out as pdf

Comment: Thanks. I have set EPS output in CutePDF, but when I try to "convert to EPS" in GSView to set the bounding box (step 4 in my question) it says "An EPS file must be  single page document". It seems the EPS file that CutePDF generates has some problem with paging

Comment: Also, the file printed by CutePDF with EPS option begins wiith `%PDF-1.4` and has default extension `pdf`. So it doesn't seem to be an EPS file at all. Can you produce EPS with CutetPDF?

Comment: Yes I have it working. I downloaded and installed CutePDF today, so it's not a different version issue. The eps file it generated was a genuine eps file. Are you sure your eps setting has not got set back somehow?

Comment: I installed today too. Do you have Windows 10? Can you tell me exactly how you configured CurePDF? I used [this option](http://s14.postimg.org/e79ncbrbl/Sin_t_tulo.png) but the file is a PDF

Comment: My settings are identical to yours (except in English). Yes I have windows 10. Is it possible you are printing a doc with more than one page?

Comment: It's a single page. I also marked "print this page only" in Word. Does your setting with CutePDF produce a file with extension `.pdf` like mine? In the "save as" dialog I can only choose `.pdf`

Comment: I am providing a full name including extension. I.,e. I type: myfigure.eps when choosing the name of the file. I am printing charts from excel. Ironically, I found that setting to eps gave me figures with weird margins even after fixing the bounding box. So now I am using "optimise for speed" instead and it gets printed in ps format, but I then convert to eps as you suggest above.

Comment: But regardless of the typed extension, if I open the file with a text editor the beginning of the file contents are `%PDF-1.4`[...]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35352/discussion-between-peter-a-and-luis-mendo).

Comment: or use http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

1. Install Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional. Other versions probably work as well.
2. From Word, print to pdf using Adobe's printer installed in step 1. Other pdf printers probably work as well.
3. Open the generated pdf file with Adobe Acrobat Professional and crop it.

The file resulting from step 3 can be included in LaTeX files without problems.

This answer is not completely satisfactory because of the following two issues, so I won't mark it as accepted:

- I get a pdf file but not an eps file. That means I can compile the tex file into pdf, but not into ps.
- This solution requires a software tool (Adobe Acrobat Proferssional) which is not free.